# Identification of artwork linked to the Horus Heresy novel series

Tags: story-identification, warhammer-40k, horus-heresy, art

I'm looking to identify the source and artist of the below artwork linked to the Games Workshop Horus Heresy series.

[image: death Guard]

The image is commonly used to represent the release of a life eater virus by Space Marine Death Guard serfs, and is specifically quoted to be:

*The Death Guard Legion's Captain Ignatius Grulgor's traitorous subordinates suffer a grisly fate after being accidentally exposed to the Life-Eater Virus aboard the frigate Eisenstein during the Istvaan III Atrocity at the start of the Horus Heresy.*

A reverse Google image search identifies the image in three locations:

- [Warhammer 40k fandom page about Virus Bombs](https://warhammer40k.fandom.com/wiki/Virus_Bomb)
- [Wordpress site about the 5th Horus Heresy Novel Flight of the Eisenstein](https://timewalkerauthor.wordpress.com/tag/malcador-the-sigillite/)
- [Facebook Warhammer 40K Meme group](https://m.facebook.com/513warhammer40kmemepage/posts/1070100963198513/?locale2=zh_CN)

While not returned in a Google Image search the image is also used on the [Eisenstein](https://warhammer40k.fandom.com/wiki/Eisenstein) fandom wiki page.

As far as I have been able to tell none of these sources directly identify the artist or the source of the work.

The novel [Flight of the Eisenstein](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/80155.The_Flight_of_the_Eisenstein) is a paperback and does not contain such artwork, and I am not aware of a special edition of this book.

I also feel that the artwork is actually representative of a later story in the novel series, but I cannot at this time remember which one it reminds me of.

Comment: You can actually find it [all over the web](https://www.google.com/search?tbs=sbi:AMhZZitXJ2Igfkvihu1I6F4b-CyNqpzbkOeczmzGADM4wP3vLhOolKTApzGk3w_1eXyQl_1CzVRjg1-HipyKFD-u2_1J7Ai5lXMy_11XxZWp4pDcrGnVkaQMRxWy8KnoJAyw_1Xyw6h6ViEUuM_10SHFhEWOT1Fn_12Finksg&ei=2QU2Y4nCE7SpptQP0_y-uAc&start=0&sa=N&ved=2ahUKEwjJkv2V8br6AhW0lIkEHVO-D3c4FBDy0wN6BAgBEDs&biw=1560&bih=853&dpr=1).  It seems more associated with "Nurgle's Rot" than "virus bomb" or "Eisenstein" though.  Nowhere is it attributed.

Comment: Searched every source I know, apparently, the image was in Visions of Heresy. Maybe somebody owning the book can give you more infos.

Comment: It must be in either the 2013 or the 2018 versions of the Artbooks as I've checked my 2007 version of Horus Heresy: Collected Visions and it's not in there as far as I can tell

Answer (score 3):

**Karl Richardson**

The [Warhammer 40K Lexicanum's artist page](https://wh40k.lexicanum.com/wiki/Artists) identifies Karl Richardson as the interior artist of *The Flight of the Eisenstein* novel.

Richardson's art on [his Facebook page](https://www.facebook.com/karlrichardsonart/photos) shows a variety of styles, but the image below - another Warhammer 40K illustration - has the exact same color scheme as the Life-Eater Virus image, another reason to believe he is the artist.

I have contacted him to confirm this, but haven't got an answer yet; so until then,consider this a partial answer.

[image]

Comment: Niel Roberts is record as the cover artist of the paperback version. I know the covers are replicated on the internal pages of the paperback covers, but I don't know what was down for the hardbacks

Comment: No response from Karl Richardson.